# Scrapy: scraping large PDF files without keeping response body in memory

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Let's say I want to scrape a PDF of 1GB with Scrapy, then using the scraped PDF data in further Requests down the line.. how do I do this without keeping the 1GB response body in memory?

(pseudo code:)

```
class MySpider:

    def start_requests(self):
        return Request('https://my-large-pdf.pdf', self.parse_pdf)

    def parse_pdf(self, pdf_response):
        some_calculated_value = my_pdf_reader(pdf_response.body)
        for i in range(1000):
            yield Request(f'another-interesting-file-{i}.html', self.parse_interesting_file, cb_kwargs=dict(some_calculated_value=some_calculated_value))

    def parse_interesting_file(self, file_response, some_calculated_value=None):
        title = file_response.css('h1')
        yield { title: f'{title} {some_calculated_value}' }
```

The 1GB stays in memory until all items from the 1000 interesting-file's are scraped, while I no longer need the PDF response body (only the calculated value that I'm passing down).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of loading whole **pdf file** in **parse_pdf** function, try loading the pdf file inside **start_requests** and then make a "**python generator**" for getting urls/patterns from the pdf file and branching further with usual '**yield Request**(...)' method of scrapy. This should save you from loading whole pdf file in to the memory and you will still have access to it content.

A part from above suggestions, did you try getting content from pdf **once** and storing it in csv file instead for late use? This should save you from all troubles that you are having with huge pdf file(s).

Comment: Thanks for thinking along! I would like to let scrapy schedule the PDF download request so it adheres to all the scrapy logic like max concurrent requests, retries, caching, etc.    

To your question about downloading once, yes it is cached after the first download.  
 

Perhaps a custom download handler that saves the PDF to disk chunk by chunk is a way to go.